# Error validating verification code when requesting Facebook access Token Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using Facebook API. I am developing it in ASP.NET 4.5/C#.

i try to get the access token on the serverside. Here's the part of the code that I get the exception from:

```
dynamic response = fb.Get("oauth/access_token",
    new  { 
     client_id = appid,
     redirect_uri = redirectURL,
    client_secret = appSecret,
    code = facebookCode 
    });
```

When I try to login, I get the following exception:

(OAuthException - #100) Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

I viewed other related question about this subject, and I checked the end slash and tried with encoded URL, but nothing works.
this is how my Valid OAuth redirect URIs on facebook app looks like:

[image]

The URL I pass for the redirect_uri parameter is (I run and test my site locally):

"http://localhost:81/Datapipes/Confirm/facebook/"

I am using the Facebook SDK for .NET by Outercurve Foundation version 7.0.6, which I installed via Nuget.

any help appreciated...

Comment: You need to use the exact same redirect_uri value at this point, as you used when generating the URL to call the login dialog.

Comment: thank you very much @CBroe it helped, finally:)

Answer (score 0):

need to use the exact same redirect_uri value at this point, as you used when generating the URL to call the login dialog
thanks to @CBroe